# Why iOS AdMob ad shows only on swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm using the latest AdMob sdk 7.0.0 and swift. I have an app with navigation controller. For the banner I've created a UIView and set it's custom class to GADBannerView. Ads are displaying at the bottom of the screen, but only when you swipe up. What could be wrong?
Here's the code:

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1111111111"

        self.bannerView.rootViewController = self
        var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()

        return self.bannerView.loadRequest(request)

    }
}
```

What could be going wrong?